# Rural Postman Without Return in Euclidean Complete Graph

Tags: algorithm, traveling-salesman

How to solve Rural Postman Problem (RPP) without returning to the start point in Euclidean Complete Graph efficiently?

A simple understanding of this problem is: Given some line segments in 2D space, find the shortest path that goes through all of them

I Googled a lot and found a lot of papers about standard RPP which do returns. How can I modify them to find the shortest path that does not require returning?

Also, the RPP problem is NP-Hard. Since the graph here have some nice properties (i.e. Euclidean, complete), are there any optimizations that can be made? I believe this problem is already studied in the industry (e.g. robot arm moving for things like gluing), I feel I can get some answer here.

Thank you!

Comment: Is the starting point set or can it be chosen?

Comment: Perhaps for all possible pairs of 2 nodes that are starting and ending point (if they aren't set), you could find the minimum sum(weight*flow) of the flow from one to the other, while each edge has at least the flow 1? With LP or IP.

Comment: Perhaps use LP to find the best pair and then IP to get a valid solution. Then if there is extra time, try out some other pairs the LP thought were good to possibly improve the solution with IP.

Comment: @Mederr It can be chosen. I'm still thinking about your solution